How to use SSH key with SCP only and not SSH, etc…?
I needed to script some SCP operations, so I used ssh-keygen and ssh-copy-id to allow me to run it without entering a password every time.
However, SSH now works without a password, too: I can just SSH to the server and it will log me right in. I don't need SSH itself to work without a password, so for security practices I'd like to disable that.
I'm certainly missing something obvious, but how can I make it so that the shared key is used only for SCP but SSH will still require a password?

SCP is essentially file transfer over an SSH connection I am not sure what you want is realistic

scp uses ssh as transport, regardless if it uses SCP or SFTP (see "History, SCP and SFTP" in this answer for insight). In ~/.ssh/config you can define two Hosts pointing to the same Hostname and Port, one using, the other not using the key; then use one host with scp, the other with ssh. Still, if the key leaks out then an attacker will be able to ssh, you are only limiting yourself. Even if you restrict the key to (e.g.) command="internal-sftp" on the server, it won't be enough.

What exact "security practices" do you mean? If you want to be on the safe side in case the private key file leaks out, then protect it with a passphrase. On the client use an agent, so you type the passphrase just once. If you are afraid that local root is rogue and will use your agent anyway then consider that root can set up modified ssh or the entire kernel. What you want to do will not save you in case your unprotected key leaks out, if an attacker using the key is able to modify (via scp) your authorized_keys, authorized_keys2, .bashrc or so on the server.
